# Wi-Fi Static Ip on a Macbook-Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I have a Macbook Pro Mid 2012 with Mountain Lion. The goal is to have an ip address that never changes, even after reboot or changing to a different wireless network.

I followed the steps from this link - http://www.macinstruct.com/node/550 and it works for 'ethernet' connections. It tells you to go to network advanced settings and to use  "Using DHCP with Manual Address" under the TCP/IP tab.

**It does not work for 'Wi-Fi' connections. Does anybody know how to make it work for 'Wi-Fi'?**

Comment: Do you mean "It doesn't work because it still sets the address from DHCP" or "It doesn't work because it sets the address and nothing can access the network?"

Comment: → Alan: +1 !
→ Nick: the receipe you quoted may fail in many company networks. With such a receipe you might easily be stealing an already attributed IP address.
Guess what happen when this @IP is just the one of your router or the one of the company mail server?

Comment: Heed the comments above. The link you reference also suggests creating a new network location. This will allow you to set an _appropriate_ and usable static IP assignment in the wifi network you're trying to use this way, while still allowing dynamic assignment with DHCP in all other wifi networks. You should do this, as grabbing a random IP address in other networks can fail a number of ways, including being on the wrong network or trying to use an address already assigned to an active device.

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you for your time! This is a company network so I am strongly considering your advice. It seems that I should get the network admin involved since I am a programmer.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have the correct gateway and netmask, and after setting your IP address information you click OK, then click Apply on the original network screen.

[image: Network Preference Pane]

[image: IPv4 Address]

Answer (score 0):

When using a manually set IP address, Wifi will not connect to the Internet if you do not have a correct DNS address set in the left hand pane on the DNS tab in the Advanced settings section. To do this, in that pane click the plus sign below and enter the correct DNS address. Click OK and don't forget to click on the Apply button when returning to the main Network window.

Comment: how do I know what is the correct DNS?